# Is it possible to make a jquery selector take in a variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, dynamic

I have links dynamically displaying on a page, their IDs are also dynamically created.

Can I do something like this:

```
$('#dynamicVariable').otherStuff();
```

I've been trying different things like:

```
var whatever = "'#"+originalVariable+"'";

$(whatever).doStuff();
```

None of this is working. Is there a correct way to do this? Or is it just not possible?

When the user clicks a link, I want something like a check mark to display next to each link clicked. The problem as I said above, is these are all dynamically created, so I can't hard code anything in.

Comment: Could you please provide a working example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
var whatever = "#"+originalVariable;
```

You want whatever to be a string equal to "#foo" not "'#foo'"

The outside quotes don't actually exist ... It's just a way to tell the parser you are describing a string.

Answer (score 4):

Remove the extra quote which is completely unnecessary in a selector.

```
var whatever = "#" + originalVariable;
//           --^--                        
$(whatever).doStuff();
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure. The selector looks for a valid selector, supplied as a string. So, any way you build that valid string is up to you.

**In your case, you had a string that contained an extra set of quotes, so while you had a valid string, you didn't have a valid selector.**

```js
var originalVariable = $("div")[0].id;
console.log(originalVariable);
$("#" + originalVariable).html("Gotcha!");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="whatever"></div>
```